# Please follow the Lines of code and cover the code 75%

Tags: apex

## Class:

```
public class AcccountControllerPage {

    public List<Schema.Account> accountpages {get;set;}
    public List<schema.Opportunity> opss{get;set;}    


    public AcccountControllerPage(){


        accountpages = [select id,Name,Industry,Type,site From Account where RecordTypeId='01228000000vFn0' anD Type='Prospect' ];

        opss =[select id,Name,StageName from Opportunity limit 10];  


    }
}
```

## TestClass:

```
@istest

public class UnitTestAccountControllerPage {


    public static testmethod void AccountControllerpageTest(){
        schema.Account a = new schema.Account();
        a.Name ='Renu';
        a.Industry ='Education';
        a.Type ='Prospect';
        a.Active__c ='yes';
        a.SLAExpirationDate__c =System.today();
        a.SLA__c ='test';
        a.SLASerialNumber__c='12345';
        insert a;

        schema.opportunity o = new schema.Opportunity();
        o.Name  ='ibm';
        o.StageName ='Prospecting';
        o.CloseDate = system.today();
        insert o;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To test a controller you need to create an instance of the controller, invoke the various methods (if the controller has methods) and check the property values that the Visualforce page will use.

So add this to the end of your test method to run the controller's constructor and do a basic check on the results:

```
AcccountControllerPage controller = new AcccountControllerPage();
System.assertEquals(1, controller.accountpages.size());
System.assertEquals(1, controller.opss.size());
```

Note that if the default record type Id for Account is not '01228000000vFn0' the first assertion will fail. Also add more assertions as you develop the code.

If you haven't already, I strongly suggest you work through this [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/apex_testing) Trailhead module.

Comment: @user38274 No problem. Do remember that the point of tests is to verify the behaviour of the code not just to get coverage so always think about the expected results of the code and add assertions to confirm those results.